# How to set up a file that I can run through my command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash, file

I am using Sublime Text and Ruby on Rails. Everything is installed.

How do I set up a file like `random.rb`

that I can navigate to in my git bash and run its contents.

The main reason I want to do this is to play with classes, methods and functions and see their outputs. `IRB` is not enough for when I want to build entire functions, etc.

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Load a file in `IRB` with definitions to play with them?

Comment: The questions was answered by @Ajay thanks!

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us who answered it. We can see that once you select the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First example: simply run your Ruby code from the IRB prompt:

```
 $ irb 
 > puts 'playing in irb prompt'
```

Second example: write your Ruby code to a ".rb" file and run it by using `ruby file_name.rb`:

```
  #test.rb
   puts 'Hello World' 
  $ ruby test.rb 
   -> "Hello world"
```

Third example: from Rails' console, you can run your .rb file:

```
  $ rails console 
  $ eval(File.read 'test.rb')
  -> 'Hello world' 
   #make sure your test.rb file resides in your project root directory.
```

Fourth example: use `rails console` to interact with your application model:

```
   $ rails console 
   $ User.all #depending on what model you have.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I almost had it but did not know I had to type 'ruby' before the file name. I was just writing the file name and kept getting command not found.